# Refactoring - Going from specific to generic interfaces

Tags: java, generics, interface, refactoring

I have a question about **refactoring** and how to **make interfaces and classes generic**.

**Suppose I have the following situation:** 
Before a plane can take off, a number of checks (validations) must be made. 
Some of these validations are on plane-level (e.g. plane has enough fuel). 
Other validations are on passenger-level (e.g. seatbelt is fastened).

**The idea is as follows:** 
You can write a number of validation rules (fragments), that test specific criteria. 
For instance, you can have the plane-level validators: EnoughFuelValidatorFragment and WorkingLightsValidatorFragment. 
Similarly, you can have the passenger-level validators: SeatbeltFastenedValidatorFragment and PersonInRightSpotValidatorFragment.

**Now**, I have written two interfaces PlaneValidatorFragment and PassengerValidatorFragment, with inner classes FragmentSequenceRunner and FragmentSequenceBuilder. The intention is to invoke a selection of validator fragments based on the TYPE_OF_PLANE and TYPE_OF_PASSENGER. The FragmentSequenceBuilder "chains" a selection of validators, whereas FragmentSequenceRunner runs validation on all selected validators.

```
public interface PlaneValidatorFragment {

    List<ErrorMessages> validate(TYPE_OF_PLANE);

    class FragmentSequenceRunner implements PlaneValidatorFragment {
        // ...

        @Override
        List<ErrorMessages> validate(TYPE_OF_PLANE) {
            // Override implementation of validate() here. 
        }
    }

    class FragmentSequenceBuilder {
        // Enough to build the sequence of validation fragments. 
    }
}

public interface PassengerValidatorFragment {

    List<ErrorMessages> validate(TYPE_OF_PASSENGER, TYPE_OF_PLANE);

    class FragmentSequenceRunner implements PassengerValidatorFragment {
        // ...

        @Override
        List<ErrorMessages> validate(TYPE_OF_PASSENGER, TYPE_OF_PLANE) {
            // Override implementation of validate() here.
        }
    }

    class FragmentSequenceBuilder {
        // Enough to buikd the sequence of validation fragments.
    }

}
```

**The idea is to be able to do something like this:**
Create a validator for any airplane type (e.g. Boeing737Validator), and check take off validation by selecting a number of existing validator fragments to run.

Assume TYPE_OF_PLANE and TYPE_OF_PASSENGER are defined as classes, such as: 
- Boeing737
- AirbusA300
- BusinessClass
- EconomyClass

**Muy current implementation is NOT generic.** Instead of having PlaneValidatorFragment and PassengerValidatorFragment, I have Boeing737PlaneValidatorFragment and Boeing737PassengerValidatorFragment.

```
public interface Boeing737PlaneValidatorFragment {

    List<ErrorMessages> validate(Boeing737);

    class FragmentSequenceRunner implements Boeing737PlaneValidatorFragment {

        @Override
        List<ErrorMessages> validate(Boeing737) {...}
    }

    class FragmentSequenceBuilder {...}
}

public interface Boeing737PassengerValidatorFragment {

    List<ErrorMessages> validate(EconomyClass, Boeing737);

    class FragmentSequenceRunner implements Boeing737PassengerValidatorFragment {

        @Override
        List<ErrorMessages> validate(EconomyClass, Boeing737) {...}
    }

    class FragmentSequenceBuilder {...}

}
```

Herein, the TYPE_OF_PLANE and TYPE_OF_PASSENGER is explicitly defined. Instead, **I would like to make the interfaces generic**, to work with all types of planes and passengers (provide a Class as a parameter).

Something like the following:

```
public interface PlaneValidatorFragment<T> {

    List<ErrorMessages> validate(T typeOfPlane);

    class FragmentSequenceRunner<T> implements PlaneValidatorFragment<T> {

        @Override
        List<ErrorMessages> validate(T typeOfPlane) {...}
    }

    class FragmentSequenceBuilder {
        // Enough to build the sequence of validation fragments. 
    }
}

public interface PassengerValidatorFragment<T, S> {

    List<ErrorMessages> validate(T typeOfPassenger, S typeOfPlane);

    class FragmentSequenceRunner<T, S> implements PassengerValidatorFragment<T, S> {

        @Override
        List<ErrorMessages> validate(T typeOfPassenger, S typeOfPlane) {...}
    }

    class FragmentSequenceBuilder {
        List<PassengerValidatorFragment<T, S>> fragments; 
    }

}
```

**TL;DR:** 
How can I make the interfaces PlaneValidatorFragment and PassengerValidatorFragment generic? 
That is; how can I parameterise them to take in TYPE_OF_PLANE and TYPE_OF_PASSENGER (as classes).

**Am I on the right track?**

Comment: You could either create an interface for `Plane` and `Passenger` or make them enums

Comment: or even for scoped objects can use `? super/extends SomeInterface`